# backbone collection add validation

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to validate/constrain that the collection can have only a certain number of models. When there is a request to add more to the collection it must either throw a message or LIFO kind of approach by which the last added model is thrown out and add the new model.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind an event on add and then call [pop](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-pop)

```
initialize: function(){

    this.on("add", function(){ this.checkLimit(); }
}

checkLimit: function() {

   if (this.length > this.limit)
      this.pop();
   }

}
```